# iPad malware warning

Tags: ipad

I got a warning that I have a malware error 800 something and I need to contact a certain phone #. I know this is bogus but the warning pops up every time I log into safari and will not let me type anything in the search bar or anywhere else for that matter how can I get rid of this

Comment: Could it be [a malware-compromised router](http://blog.codinghorror.com/welcome-to-the-internet-of-compromised-things/)?

Answer (score 17):

I think @toni is just talking about a page that tries to stop you from navigating away.

Before you do anything else, double-tap the iPad's home button & close Safari.

You can then clear out all your open tabs:

- In iOS 8 and later, Settings > Safari > Clear History and Website Data
- In iOS 6 and earlier, Settings > Safari > Clear Cookies and Data

If you want to preserve your tabs & history:

1. Go to Settings > Safari > Advanced
2. Turn off JavaScript.
3. Open Safari & close the problem tab.
4. Turn JavaScript back on.

Comment: Notice that if Safari is running, some elements in the cache may not be cleaned up. Closing and making sure it is closed is important!

Answer (score 2):

The best course of action is to visit an Apple Store and [ask an Apple Genius](https://www.apple.com/retail/geniusbar/) for help.

They will be best placed to help fix the specific problem you are seeing. Also your visit will help Apple understand how widespread the problem is and what malware is taking hold.

Once your iPad is fixed, Apple provide this advice on how to [turn on anti-phishing protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201265):

> ### Turn on Anti-phishing
>
> To turn Anti-phishing on, tap **Settings > Safari** and turn on **Fraudulent Website Warning**. When it's on, the Anti-phishing feature in Safari will show an alert if the site you're visiting is a suspected phishing site. To turn it off, tap Fraudulent Website Warning again.
>
> Phishing is a fraudulent attempt to steal your personal information, such as passwords, account information, or user names. A fraudulent website masquerades as a legitimate one, such as a bank, financial institution, or email service provider.

Comment: The other answer (by @null) is what the Apple Store would (hopefully) do but they might try to get you to pay a replacement fee for a new device. Generally that would be the absolute last-resort.

Comment: I suspect the country, warranty, and AppleCare status of the device will also have an impact but I would surprised to be charged for the process suggested. I have found the Apple Store very helpful.

Comment: Oh I wouldn't expect to be charged for that, but I wouldn't be surprised if they told me it "needed" to be replaced (when really they just can't figure out how to fix it). The Apple Store staff at my local mall aren't trained very well; but your mileage may vary.